# Load an asset at random each page load

Tags: assets, image

I have a single that has 5 banner images. I would like to load a different image each time the page loads. I want to do this with twig not JS, is this possible if so could somone point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply using `'RAND()'` in the order parameter does the trick.

```
{% for image in entry.banner.limit(1).order('RAND()') %}
  {{ image.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to see if the same thing could be accomplished using Craft's shuffle function.  At first, I was looping through the image array and using an if statement to grab the first one:

```
{% for image in shuffle(entry.banner) %}
    {% if loop.first %}
        {{ image.url }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then, I realized there was a less verbose option:

```
{% set image = shuffle(entry.banner)[0] %}
{{ image.url }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of getting a random image from image set in Craft 3

```
{{ shuffle(entry.bgImg.all())[0].getUrl('1900x1050') }}
```